# Processing files with spaces in their name

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

I have many big csv files under many folders and the file and folder have spaces in their names.

I now have the code below but it doesn't work when the file/folder has spaces in the name:

```
csv=$(find . -name "*.csv")

for f in $csv; do
  echo "Compressing $f"
  (cd $(dirname $f) && zip -j $(basename $f.zip) $(basename $f))
done
```

Comment: Why `zip`, rather than `gzip`?

Comment: In general, you want to use `find -exec` to avoid space problems.

Comment: hi o11c,because this is a file server, windows user need access files without   software installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `find` execute zip itself, since it still knows about all the spaces:

```
find -name '*.csv' -exec zip -j {}.zip {} \;
```

A direct port of what you wrote would use `-execdir` in place of `-exec`, but it appears not to be necessary.

Comment: one more question. Is there a way to execute touch csvfile zipfile then remove csv file with one command? I tried find -name '*.csv' -exec (zip -j {}.zip {} && touch {} {}.zip) \; but didn't work for me.

Comment: `find` doesn't use a shell ... use multiple `-exec` lines, `-a` is implicit. Also `-delete` exists for the removal stage.